# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid path or file name

Tags: json, visual-foxpro

i have the following code which has been getting me data from flat files. but now all of a sudden i am  getting this error

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Invalid path or file name
```

but the code hasnt changed it worked for months,im not sure what went wrong.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonText;
    System.Collections.Generic.List<object> objList = new List<object>();
    string strConn = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=\\10.0.0.0\wwwroot\apps\assembly\FlatDatabaseDbfs\vt_Flat.dbf;Collating Sequence=machine;";

    using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConn))
    {          
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmddbf = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
            cmddbf.Connection = conn;

            conn.Open();

        cmddbf.CommandText = "select * from vt_Flat";

        var dr = cmddbf.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            objList.Add(new
            {

                Code = (dr["dp_code"].ToString().Trim()),

            });
        };

    } 

    var filteredList = objList.Where(obj => ((dynamic)obj).Status == (Request.QueryString["Status"] ?? "") && ((dynamic)obj).DepCode == (Request.QueryString["Code"] ?? ""));

    jsonText = json.Serialize(filteredList);
    Response.Write(jsonText);


}
```

is there something wrong with iis permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the connection having to point to the PATH as already noted by Oleg, in the C# instances of OleDbConnection I have done in the past, the connection string uses

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1
```

Don't know if it is case/sensitive issue and the ".1" which is also part of the provider string.

Once you have a valid connection to the PATH, then your query can query from any table within the path location.  So if you had 2+ files, and needed to join them, you would do so with a standard query / join.  In your case, your command text is only "select *" since you changed your original connection that included the table.  Change the command text to

```
"select * from vt_Flat"
```

**OTHER CONSIDERATIONS**

Is this being run from some web service project?  If so, THAT could be the basis.  You as a developer testing are running with your permissions / access.  If running as a web server, the WEB-based user account may not have permissions to the folder to process / work with the data.

Check the folder of your production data to ALLOW the web user if so running.  If that doesn't work, set permissions on the folder to EVERYBODY (only for testing/confirmation purposes only).  See if that is the problem.

Also, from the Provider connection, did you try with it as all upper case VFPOLEDB.1?

Comment: hi.i tried the .1 before it still gives the same error,and my apologies,i do have it as select * from vt_flat in my program,i never see i missed it out here in this code

Comment: @doe, see revised answer

Comment: ok it works now,i changed it to VFPOLEDB. and i changed the path of the file .thanks for the assistance

Comment: @doe, don't forget to mark as solved so others know too. (quick read on help -> tour for site etiquette)

Answer (score 0):

Use path instead of file name, e.g.:

```
Data Source=\\10.0.0.0\wwwroot\apps\assembly\FlatDatabaseDbfs\;
```

Comment: tried that now ,its still giving the same error,i checked permission to the files and nothing changed

Comment: Try to use computer name instead of IP address then.

Comment: did that aswell,it was working before i dont understand what went wrong,if i run the same code on my local machine it will work but if i run it on the server i get that error

Comment: M.b. there are some restrictions on your network? Don't even know what to suppose